# How can I find the shared data/folders of a windows pc?

Tags: c++, networking

I'm looking to find a way where I can have an ip from a pc on my network and then scan it for shared folders.
I know how to find those ip's that isn't the problem but is it possible to search for shared folders per ip without knowing the actual name of that shared data?

I was thinking of something resembling c# where you can get all accessible files from a selected directory.

Oh, if possible, can this be done in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use `NetShareEnum` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See the example on the page.